# comma delimited list using coalesce

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone explain me how to generate a comma delimited list using COALESCE function?

Consider i have a simple table

```
test(id SMALLINT,name VARCHAR(10))
```

and i want the names of all tuples with id > 0 in a comma delimited list..

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql

```
select group_concat(name) from test where id>10;
```

Comment: Thanks this helped..But was curious how to use the coalesce function?

Comment: The COALESCE function is for selecting the second value when the first one IS NULL. Or the third when the second one IS NULL. etc... It doesn't select a comma delimited list, you supply a comma delimited list (actually just multiple arguments) which values to read for the first non NULL.

Comment: I tried the above query, but it returns the form of a table. I actually wanted it in a string. 

For example: 'x,y,z'

Comment: In SQL Server you can use this approach http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#cat not sure if it directly translates to MySQL (possibly it would)

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(group_concat( name separator ', ')) from test where id>0;
```